# ymaps,geocode не выводит координаты

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Есть код:

```
<Map
    modules={["geocode"]}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    defaultState={{
      center: userLocation || defaultCityCoordinates,
      zoom: zoom,
    }}
    onLoad={ (ymaps) => {
      var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode('Москва, Сверчков переулок');
      console.log(myGeocoder) // Если это убрать, то вообще ничего не выведет
      myGeocoder.then(
        (res) => {
          //выуживаем массив результатов
          var objs = res.geoObjects.toArray();

          let i = 0;
          //выводим их в консоль
          objs.forEach(
            i => {
              console.log(objs[i].properties.getAll());
            }
          )
        }
      );}
    }
  >
```

При его выполнении в консоль выводит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

metaData:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так может в mataData чего есть?

Comment: @SwaD прикрепил в изменении, но вроде ничего нет

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что res.geoObjects — это массив результатов? Каждый конкретный объект следует получать методом res.geoObjects.get(i), а их массив сейчас находится по более сложному (и вполне может быть непостоянному) пути geoObjects._collectionComponent._baseArrayComponent._children

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменил onLoad:

```
onLoad={ (ymaps) => {
      ymaps.geocode('Москва, Красная площадь')
      .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
      });
      ;}
    }
```

Всё работает